# Jenkins Auto Build post Url 404 Issue

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have configured a jenkins server{url} and now configuring build on commit push.

I want to have a post url which gets called on every commit and merge. I have set the triggers in bitbucket for the same.

The url is (format specified by jenkins)
JENKINS_URL/job/App/build?token=TOKEN_NAME

When I run the url from browser after login to jenkins everything is working fine.

The issue is, bitbucket is showing the status of the post request as 404.

I have reproduced the issue by executing the url after logged out.

Since these users would be going into Anonymous category, I have checked permissions for the same.
For anonymous users the permission were set to Read and Run Scripts

Please don't post direct answer. Just guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless anonymous has Job/Read, you would need to use the Build Token Root plugin to create an alternate URL endpoint to trigger builds.